# How to use Class.cs in form1

Tags: c#, winforms

[This is how my tab control looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4yNT.jpg) Basically, I have a tabcontrol of let's say 4 items, `detector` `camera` `lens` `focus`. Instead of writing a bunch of codes all together in my form1.cs, I've created a class and wrote my codes in classes `detector.cs`, `camera.cs` `lens.cs` and `focus.cs`, however now I`m stuck as to how do I combine them together with my form1 so that the code will work?

*If I put everything in form1.cs it will work. However, when I create a new class and shift the codes over it doesn't work anymore. I've never separated them before. But I feel that separating them is a lot neater when viewing the codes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CamTest
{
    class Camera
    {
        private void CboOut_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboOut.SelectedIndex;
            cmd = 0x101E;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                val = 0x03;
            }
            else if (num == 1)
            {
                val = 0x02;
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                val = 0x01;
            }
            else
            {
                val = 0x00;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void CboPol_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboPol.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x1030;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1031;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void CboAmp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboAmp.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x102A;
            }
            else if (num == 1)
            {
                cmd = 0x102B;
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                cmd = 0x102C;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x102D;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void CboPro_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboPro.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x1017;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1016;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void CboFlip_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboFlip.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x1050;
            }
            else if (num == 1)
            {
                cmd = 0x1051;
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                cmd = 0x1052;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1053;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void chkboxDDE_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            byte lit_val, lar_val;
            cmd = 0x1019;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxDDE.Checked)
            {
                lit_val = (byte)trkbarFine.Value;
                lar_val = (byte)trkbarCoarse.Value;
                val = (byte)((lar_val << 4) + lit_val);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1018;
                len = 0x0000;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void TrkbarFine_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            byte lit_val, lar_val;
            cmd = 0x1019;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxDDE.Checked)
            {
                lit_val = (byte)trkbarFine.Value;
                lar_val = (byte)trkbarCoarse.Value;
                val = (byte)((lar_val << 4) + lit_val);
            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void TrkbarCoarse_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            byte lit_val, lar_val;
            cmd = 0x1019;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxDDE.Checked)
            {
                lit_val = (byte)trkbarFine.Value;
                lar_val = (byte)trkbarCoarse.Value;
                val = (byte)((lar_val << 4) + lit_val);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void chkboxMan_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            uint gain, offset;
            cmd = 0x1020;
            len = 0x0004;

            if (chkboxMan.Checked)
            {
                gain = (uint)trkbarCon.Value;
                offset = (uint)trkbarBright.Value;
                val = (gain << 16) + offset;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1021;
                len = 0x0000;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void TrkbarCon_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            uint gain, offset;
            cmd = 0x1020;
            len = 0x0004;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxMan.Checked)
            {
                gain = (uint)trkbarCon.Value;
                offset = (uint)trkbarBright.Value;
                val = (gain << 16) + offset;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void TrkbarBright_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            uint gain, offset;
            len = 0x0004;
            cmd = 0x1020;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxMan.Checked)
            {
                gain = (uint)trkbarCon.Value;
                offset = (uint)trkbarBright.Value;
                val = (gain << 16) + offset;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void chkboxCursor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            len = 0x0001;
            cmd = 0x1034;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxCursor.Checked)
            {
                val = 0x01;
            }
            else
            {
                val = 0x00;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void SendPosition(int Ypos, int Xpos)
        {
            ///Declaration
            cmd = 0x1035;
            len = 0x0004;

            ///Code
            val = (uint)((Ypos << 16) + Xpos);

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        private void btnTt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if ((y - 16) < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y -= 16;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if (y <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y--;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if (y >= (height - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y++;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnDd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if ((y + 16) > (height - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y += 16;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if (x <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x--;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnLl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if ((x - 16) < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x -= 16;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if (x >= (width - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x++;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnRr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if ((x + 16) > (width - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x += 16;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        private void BtnMid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtboxX.Text = (width / 2).ToString();
            txtboxY.Text = (height / 2).ToString();

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }
    }
}
```

*note all the buttons and textbox are in form1, hence unable to be detected. I just want to link them together so the entire code works.

Comment: What code you have written in those classes? Can you share the relevant code here?

Comment: I've edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function that you want to call from  outside your class must be declared with the `public` accessibility modifier.

[From Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers):

> All types and type members have an accessibility level, which controls
>   whether they can be used from other code in your assembly or other
>   assemblies. You can use the following access modifiers to specify the
>   accessibility of a type or member when you declare it:
>
> public
>
> The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the
>   same assembly or another assembly that references it.
>
> private
>
> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same
>   class or struct.

Here I've modified your code accordingly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CamTest
{
    class Camera
    {
        public void CboOut_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboOut.SelectedIndex;
            cmd = 0x101E;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                val = 0x03;
            }
            else if (num == 1)
            {
                val = 0x02;
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                val = 0x01;
            }
            else
            {
                val = 0x00;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void CboPol_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboPol.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x1030;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1031;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void CboAmp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboAmp.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x102A;
            }
            else if (num == 1)
            {
                cmd = 0x102B;
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                cmd = 0x102C;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x102D;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void CboPro_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboPro.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x1017;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1016;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void CboFlip_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboFlip.SelectedIndex;
            len = 0x0000;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                cmd = 0x1050;
            }
            else if (num == 1)
            {
                cmd = 0x1051;
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                cmd = 0x1052;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1053;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void chkboxDDE_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            byte lit_val, lar_val;
            cmd = 0x1019;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxDDE.Checked)
            {
                lit_val = (byte)trkbarFine.Value;
                lar_val = (byte)trkbarCoarse.Value;
                val = (byte)((lar_val << 4) + lit_val);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1018;
                len = 0x0000;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void TrkbarFine_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            byte lit_val, lar_val;
            cmd = 0x1019;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxDDE.Checked)
            {
                lit_val = (byte)trkbarFine.Value;
                lar_val = (byte)trkbarCoarse.Value;
                val = (byte)((lar_val << 4) + lit_val);
            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void TrkbarCoarse_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            byte lit_val, lar_val;
            cmd = 0x1019;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxDDE.Checked)
            {
                lit_val = (byte)trkbarFine.Value;
                lar_val = (byte)trkbarCoarse.Value;
                val = (byte)((lar_val << 4) + lit_val);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void chkboxMan_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            uint gain, offset;
            cmd = 0x1020;
            len = 0x0004;

            if (chkboxMan.Checked)
            {
                gain = (uint)trkbarCon.Value;
                offset = (uint)trkbarBright.Value;
                val = (gain << 16) + offset;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = 0x1021;
                len = 0x0000;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void TrkbarCon_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            uint gain, offset;
            cmd = 0x1020;
            len = 0x0004;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxMan.Checked)
            {
                gain = (uint)trkbarCon.Value;
                offset = (uint)trkbarBright.Value;
                val = (gain << 16) + offset;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void TrkbarBright_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            uint gain, offset;
            len = 0x0004;
            cmd = 0x1020;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxMan.Checked)
            {
                gain = (uint)trkbarCon.Value;
                offset = (uint)trkbarBright.Value;
                val = (gain << 16) + offset;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void chkboxCursor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Declaration
            len = 0x0001;
            cmd = 0x1034;

            ///Code
            if (chkboxCursor.Checked)
            {
                val = 0x01;
            }
            else
            {
                val = 0x00;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void SendPosition(int Ypos, int Xpos)
        {
            ///Declaration
            cmd = 0x1035;
            len = 0x0004;

            ///Code
            val = (uint)((Ypos << 16) + Xpos);

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }

        public void btnTt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if ((y - 16) < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y -= 16;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if (y <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y--;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if (y >= (height - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y++;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnDd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int y;

            y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);

            if ((y + 16) > (height - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                y += 16;
                txtboxY.Text = y.ToString();
            }

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if (x <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x--;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnLl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if ((x - 16) < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x -= 16;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if (x >= (width - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x++;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnRr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;

            x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);

            if ((x + 16) > (width - 1))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                x += 16;
                txtboxX.Text = x.ToString();
            }

            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }

        public void BtnMid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtboxX.Text = (width / 2).ToString();
            txtboxY.Text = (height / 2).ToString();

            int x = int.Parse(txtboxX.Text);
            int y = int.Parse(txtboxY.Text);
            SendPosition(y, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Only specify `private` if you only plan to call that function from within the same class. Do note, however, that no accessibility modifier means that it's private.

Comment: oh, I see. I understand now, I replaced it however there is still the problem of for example in the first line of code where `int num = cboOut.SelectedIndex;` is, it still says 'cboOut does not exist in the current context' because the combobox is in my form 1.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very new to coding and stackoverflow, I don't really know how to use it well yet, thanks for the edit!

Comment: Oh I got it now, you just have to add form1.cboOut in order to get it from form1. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

class.Func();
Func have to be Public. Thats all.

```
namespace CamTest
{
    class Camera
    {
        public void funCForBoOut_SelectedIndexChanged()
        {
            ///Declaration
            int num = cboOut.SelectedIndex;
            cmd = 0x101E;
            len = 0x0001;

            ///Code
            if (num == 0)
            {
                val = 0x03;
            }
            else if (num == 1)
            {
                val = 0x02;
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                val = 0x01;
            }
            else
            {
                val = 0x00;
            }

            ///Pack
            Packs(len, cmd, val);
        }
}
```

> if you write your class in a dffrent namespace, you have to add "using " if your form class is written in CamTest namespace, you dont have to add it, this is just an example.

```
using CamTest
namespace form
{
class form1
        {
            private void CboOut_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {Camera.funCForBoOut_SelectedIndexChanged();}
        }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm quite new to coding, could you explain what some of the code meant and where do I place them? I am so sorry for the trouble :(